# CSS React-bootsrap nav - width greater than browser width

Tags: css, react-bootstrap

This is bugging me because it only moves right to left slightly and everything is offset to the right because the width is flowing over.

I have set to my navbar properties:

```
.navbar{
    background: rgb(7, 102, 197);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(7,101,195,1) 0%, rgba(0,72,144,1) 100%);
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

within index.css i also have width 100%

[image: Taking up these too many pixels (the below graphic should fit perfectly)]

From the second image you can see it is greater

[image]

I did try applying:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

But this doesn't remove the issue

Comment: is this issue only in navbar ? or the whole body is affected ?

Comment: The issue is not with the navbar. Some other element is overflowing out of body

Comment: That's what make the distance between navbar to the absolute right. somewhere in the other div there are some elements that has fixed width defined in px . that's making things wider and push out of the max-width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the width to 'device-width' in the HTML?

Because this 100% width is subjective to our device- your code works fine with the following tag added in HTML:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`